# How to modify tracking link target

Tags: magento-1.9, shipment-tracking

How to modify the tracking link on both admin and frontend so that when I click on the link `track this shipment`, it opens directly to carrier page ?

[image: tracking information]

I want it to open `https://www.paket.id/is/MPMTD` instead of `magento/shipping/tracking/[...]`

This is how I changed the carrier URL:

```
public function getTrackingInfo($tracking)
{
    $track = Mage::getModel('shipping/tracking_result_status');
    $track->setUrl('https://www.paket.id/is/' . $tracking)
       ->setTracking($tracking)
       ->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
    return $track;
}
```

I have googled how to modify this pop-up but I didn't find any solution. And, is it possible to modify it?

Comment: I just changed the tracking URL to my custom carrier. I am wondering if it's possible to modify the pop-up target? I didn't find any solution for this, so I ask here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bit of a struggle with this one, but I found how to do it.

Copy this file `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml` to your theme if you have one, or modify it directly (I'd advise against it).

Then around lines 60 you should see something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="linkId" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->helper('shipping')->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($_order) ?>','trackorder','width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')" title="<?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>
```

If you are using PHP >= 5.5 replace it with :

```
<?php  
      echo array_shift(
               Mage::getModel('shipping/info')->loadByHash(Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode("order_id:{$_order->getId()}:{$_order->getProtectCode()}"))->getTrackingInfo()
              )[0]->getData('status'); 
?>
```

if using PHP < 5.5 do this:

```
<?php 
    $firstTrack = array_shift(Mage::getModel('shipping/info')->loadByHash(Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode("order_id:{$_order->getId()}:{$_order->getProtectCode()}"))->getTrackingInfo());
    $trackLink = $firstTrack[0]->getData('status');
    echo $trackLink;
?>
```