# Magento 2 Tracking shipment with carrier URL

Tags: magento2, rest-api, shipment-tracking

I would like to know how to show the URL of a carrier to redirect the customer to carrier's tracking site, if it's possible with the tracking number in the URL.

This pal did it but for Magento 1
[How to modify tracking link target](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136214/how-to-modify-tracking-link-target)

However I cannot edit the phtml template, because this module is intended to work in different stores, so if I use app/design the purpouse of using just the module will be lost.

Here there would be an extra field called URL 
[image]

Thank you and regards!